# Is it better to store the file in the database or just the path of the file?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, file, blob

Is it better to store the file in the database or just the path of the file in question?

And especially if the volume and the file numbers are important.

Comment: You can see this topic : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Comment: and also : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not

Comment: I have to say that isn't a very useful question. If this were asked in the days of large platter hard drives and 1Mb/s network speeds then the answer might be very different. Using SSD versus HDD these days also can impact the answer. I think that there is very little that an answer to this question can offer that has long term benefit. Even the word "better", in this case, needs to be defined. The only thing you can do is try both and test what's "better" for you.

Comment: Why not both? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

> objects smaller than 256K are best stored in a database while objects
>   larger than 1M are best stored in the filesystem

You need to decide what to do with objects between 256K and 1M.

Have a read of this Microsoft Research article - which explains this: [To BLOB or Not To BLOB: Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

Notes:

- There is actually no cut and dry solution to this, you may have reasons for doing one or the other.

  For example in a highly security critical application you may decide to store everything in the db.
- There are many factors to think about. If you need to replicate your db, it helps to have everything in the db, because you can be sure your replicated db can serve up all the files
- If the application is performance critical you have a good reason to store everything on the filesystem (especially if the files are large and/or you are reading/writing them a lot)

Comment: First thanks for your answer how is very clear :being given to me that I must manage network traffic on our VPN , and also not to be forced to share a folder between users I choose the storage solution into the base .but constraint is that I have over 1000 recordings each correspant a file size of 3.5 MB

Comment: If you're using MSSS, have a look at the Filestream data type.